# Pagestyle wrong after \cleardoublepage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, double-sided

Using KOMA-script I have problems with a twosided document. I want my sections to start on an odd page, so i use `\cleardoublepage` before starting the next section. I want the section title to be displayed in the right headline and the subsection title displayed in the left headline.

Whenever a section ends on an odd page everything works fine, one empty page is added and the sections starts on the next odd page with the correct pagestyle.
But it blows up when a section ends on an even side. The new section correctly starts on the next odd page without an additional blank page but it has the wrong pagestyle and no headers at all.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,headsepline=true,twoside=true]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setheadsepline{1pt}

\rohead{\leftmark}
\lehead{\rightmark}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\section{test}
blah blah blah
\cleardoublepage
\section{test2}
\lipsum
\cleardoublepage
\section{test3}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Headers are shown on the page where section test2 starts but not on the page where section test3 starts.

What goes wrong here?

Comment: If I get it right the problem should be that in your MWE the headers of page 5 with section "test3" are missing because the section before ends on an even page?

Comment: Are you sure that the documentclass `scrartcl` is the correct choise. I think you should use `scrbook`!

Comment: On odd numbered pages you want the `\leftmark`, which is empty, because no `\chapter` command has set it.

Comment: In your example, section "test3" starts at page 5 which features the correct heading.

Comment: When I compile the above example on my computers "test3" starts on page 5 but shows no heading at all in contrast to "test2" on page 3, which does. Kubuntu 12.04 and Linux Mint 13... Both featuring very old TeXlive-Distributions (2009). What version are you using @lockstep?

Comment: Updated TeXlive 2012.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Ok maybe I just ran into a bug there which has long since been fixed. Damn Ubuntu.

Comment: @Quincy: yes that's right.
@egreg: `\leftmark` will be set by a `\section` (this is set up by `\automark`)
@MarcoDaniel: I think i will stick to scrartcl for now, i really don't want nor need another level of grouping

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in an old version of KOMA-script. It is mentioned on http://www.komascript.de/release3.06 (german, last item on the page) to be the case for the 3.06 release from July 2010 and the problem seems to exist since 3.01a from November 2008. I found no mention of a bugfix in one of the changelogs after 3.06 but it still seems to be fixed in the current version.

The aforementioned release notes proposes to add `\thispagestyle{...}` after `\cleardoublepage`. This solves the problem, at least in TexLive 2009.

Comment: Actually http://www.komascript.de/release3.06 states that it should be fixed in the next release which would have been 3.07 from September 2010.